# Shorttitles after included external file

Tags: biblatex, external-files

I have included an external pdf document with literature references in my TeX document. Afterwards, I have to cite one of the cited books again later in my normal TeX document. My problem: I work with short titles, i.e. the first reference is written out in full (e.g. von Harnack, Adolf: Die Mission und Ausbreitung des Christentums in den ersten drei Jahrhunderten...) and from the second reference onwards it is abbreviated (Harnack, Mission). Since I cite the book in the external file, the book is initially displayed in full in the TeX document. How can I get the abbreviated version in the TeX document in this case? Here is my MWE, but I was not able to attach an external file here (It works in another plattform. There I have asked the same question her, but did not get an answer. Here is the Link: https://golatex.de/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=25354 .Here is my MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Harnack.Mission2,
title = {Die Mission und Ausbreitung des Christentums in den ersten drei Jahrhunderten},
shorttitle ={Mission},
volumes = {2},
author = {von Harnack, Adolf},
location = {Leipzig},
date = {1965},
edition = {4},
keywords = {sekundaer},
related = {Harnack.Mission},
relatedtype = {reprint},
}
@book{Harnack.Mission,
  location = {Darmstadt},
  date = {2018}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[style=sbl,citepages=separate,backend=biber,sblfootnotes=false,ibidpage=true,ibidtracker=true,idemtracker=true,pagetracker=spread,sorting=nyvt,url=false,isbn=false,doi=false,clearlang=false,uniquename=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
test\footnote{Vgl. \cite[8]{Harnack.Mission2}.}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: Please always test the code you are showing. The example in your question does not show the issue and therefore is useless. Your example [at golatex](https://golatex.de/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=25354) is also not working, because the `\includepdf` command is not defined. If it is the one from package `pdfpages` it is wrongly placed in the document preamble and an optional argument is used instead of a mandatory one. So I was not able to really test your code to understand your problem and needed to guess.

I guess you need a kind of manual adding a cite to the current seen list, something like:

```latex
\newcommand*{\manualaddseen}[1]{%
  \blx@xsanitizeafter{\def\abx@field@entrykey}{#1}%
  \blx@citetracker
}
```

to be used, whenever an external document is included, that already contains cites, e.g.:

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Harnack.Mission2,
title = {Die Mission und Ausbreitung des Christentums in den ersten drei Jahrhunderten},
shorttitle ={Mission},
volumes = {2},
author = {von Harnack, Adolf},
location = {Leipzig},
date = {1965},
edition = {4},
keywords = {sekundaer},
related = {Harnack.Mission},
relatedtype = {reprint},
}
@book{Harnack.Mission,
  location = {Darmstadt},
  date = {2018}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[style=sbl,citepages=separate,backend=biber,sblfootnotes=false,ibidpage=true,ibidtracker=true,idemtracker=true,pagetracker=spread,sorting=nyvt,url=false,isbn=false,doi=false,clearlang=false,uniquename=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{pdfpages}% NOTE: Missing Package added.

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\manualaddseen}[1]{%
  \blx@xsanitizeafter{\def\abx@field@entrykey}{#1}%
  \blx@citetracker
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\includepdf{text.pdf}
\manualaddseen{Harnack.Mission2}% add the cite from the external file to the current seen list

test\footcite[Vgl.][8]{Harnack.Mission2}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note, that using `\footcite[Vgl.]` is not the best idea. If all cites should have the `Vgl.` you should re-configure the cite command instead of adding an optional argument to every `\footcite`. But this would be another question (which already should be answered elsewhere).

However, if the external file is not the first cite, this would not change the full cite of the external file to a short cite. It also does not change the format of the cite in the external file. So it could be a better idea, to cut of the cite from the external page and add a regular `\footcite` (outside the page to make it invisible):

```latex
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Harnack.Mission2,
title = {Die Mission und Ausbreitung des Christentums in den ersten drei Jahrhunderten},
shorttitle ={Mission},
volumes = {2},
author = {von Harnack, Adolf},
location = {Leipzig},
date = {1965},
edition = {4},
keywords = {sekundaer},
related = {Harnack.Mission},
relatedtype = {reprint},
}
@book{Harnack.Mission,
  location = {Darmstadt},
  date = {2018}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[style=sbl,citepages=separate,backend=biber,sblfootnotes=false,ibidpage=true,ibidtracker=true,idemtracker=true,pagetracker=spread,sorting=nyvt,url=false,isbn=false,doi=false,clearlang=false,uniquename=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{pdfpages}% NOTE: Missing Package added.

\newcommand{\somewhereinvisible}[1]{%
    \hspace*{\paperwidth}\nobreak
    #1\nobreak
    \hskip-\paperwidth
}

\begin{document}
% For a minimal working example IMHO this one would be better:
\includepdf[pagecommand={\somewhereinvisible{\footcite[682]{Harnack.Mission2}}},trim=0 100 0 0,offset=0 50,clip]{example-image-a4.pdf}

 test\footcite[8]{Harnack.Mission2}
\includepdf[pagecommand={\somewhereinvisible{\footcite[682]{Harnack.Mission2}}},trim=0 100 0
 0,offset=0 50,clip]{text.pdf}% with change of the original cite of the external file

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice answer! If you replace `\blx@citetracker@global` with `\blx@citetracker` in your first MWE, the command will respond to the `citetracker` settings more closely.

Comment: We also have a feature request for something like this at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/902, but last time I looked (it's been a while to be fair), there were a few details to think about and figure out before something like this could be implemented in core `biblatex`. (It looks like a useful feature to me.)

Comment: @moewe Thank you for the improvement suggestion. At my “reverse engineering”, I've simply searched, how “seen” is recognized and then how it is set. And because `\blx@citetracker` is defined using the other trackers, I've not found this one.

Comment: @moewe IMHO an option to also use the tracker with `\nocite{<entry key list>}` (maybe only if `\nocite` is *after* `\begin{document}`) could be an alternative to such a command.